# React Native just reinitialize iOS or Android Project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, initialization

I want to start again building my React Native app with iOS because I messed up the XCode Project and can't make it build. How can I just reinitialize the iOS project or in other cases the Android Project in my existing React Native app?

Comment: this is one reason why git or svn is essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this functionality was once implemented in react-native with the command `react-native ios` or `react-native android`, which are no longer implemented.
But I found a solution for Android [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9312#issuecomment-239254800) which is also working for iOS:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const generate = require('react-native/local-cli/generate/generate.js');

generate([
  '--platform', 'ios', //or android
  '--project-path', process.cwd(),
  '--project-name', JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8')
  ).name,
]);
```

[Credit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9312#issuecomment-239254800)

Just put this code in a script and run it with `node script-name.js`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any built in way to "reset" the native projects. When i've had to do this in the past i've just created a new project with the same name and replaced the ios and android folders in the project directory.